# A warning I don't understand using scanf() in C language

Tags: c, scanf

This is some code I wrote to exercise using malloc(). In particular, I want to have a char-array of dimension and elements given by the user and to print these elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *ptr;
    int d;
    
    printf("Inserire la dimensione dell'array CHAR:\n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    
    ptr = (char *) malloc(d * sizeof(char));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    
        printf("Inserire un char:\n");
        scanf("%c", ptr[i]);
    
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
    
        printf("%c", ptr[j]);
    
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

The compiler gives a warning at line 17: `warning: fomat "%c" expects argument of type "char", but argument 2 has type "int"`. I tried previously `scanf("%c", &ptr[i])` at line 17 which to me seems also more natural, but the code runs badly.

Comment: The `ptr[i]` is an (uninitialsed) integer value. `scanf("%c", ptr[i]);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &ptr[i]);`

Comment: How are you entering input? Did you see this note in the `scanf` manual: *The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format.* This is also an excellent time to learn how to use your debugger. You can set it up to read input from a file you prepared in advance and step through the program, inspecting variables like `d` and `ptr[i]` as the program continues.

Comment: The reason it 'ran badly' is because the <Enter> key counts as a char here... `\n`

Comment: I agree to the comments above. If you going to learn usage of malloc(): You should add some code to example that checks that "d" is not zero (and not too large) and you should also check if ptr is not NULL after the malloc(). ;-)

Comment: That is not the error message the compiler produces. It says “of type "char *"”, not “of type "char"”. That may not have prevented anybody from understanding the issue in this particular case, but, when you are working with computers, you should be precise. Copy text exactly and do not alter it.

Comment: We also already have thousands of questions about missing `&` in scanf arguments. These questions are evidently not read by future readers (or the questions wouldn't keep coming). Voting to close this as simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&ptr[i]` is the correct way, at least it does something, even though that something is wrong. The alternative (`ptr[i]`) does nothing (or even worse it is Undefined Behavior, which programmers should avoid in their code). The reason why the first code runs badly is because you must type Enter after you enter the character. The second `scanf` will read that Enter. To "consume" this Enter and any other white-space character (and also the Enter that you type when entering the length of the array) just add one space in `scanf` format:

```
scanf(" %c", &ptr[i]);
```